# Rails - passed parameter not recognized in custom service [NoMethodError]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've written a custom service for my project:

```
#app\services\quiz_data_creation.rb:
class QuizDataCreation
  def initialize(user)
    @quiz_session = user.quiz_session #<-- here is the problem
  end

  def create
    create_answer_data
  end

  private
  def create_answer_data
    @quiz_session.quiz.questions[@quiz_session.current_question_index].answers
  end
end
```

I call the create method in my ActionCable channel like this:

```
class QuizDataChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def send_data
    logger.debug "[AC] before quiz data creation service - current user: #{current_user.inspect}"
    @answers = QuizDataCreation.new(user: current_user).create
    #then send answers
  end
end
```

The problem I'm having is that the service does not recognize the user object I pass when calling the create method, even though the logger shows me that the correct object is being found! It gives me the Error Message:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method quiz_session for #<Hash:0xc86cfa0>
```

I'm using a Devise generated User. Also, it might be relevant that I'm using 2 models that inherit from the User model (Teacher and Student), but all the attributes are stored in the `users` table.

A user record looks like this:

```
[AC] before quiz data creation service - current user: #<Teacher id: 1, email: "bob@teacher.edu", created_at: "2017-05-11 07:24:48", updated_at: "2017-07-26 08:40:27", name: "Bob", quiz_session_id: 7>
```

I would be very happy if anyone could point out to me how to solve this issue - thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a positional parameter

```
def initialize(user)
```

but you pass a keyword argument:

```
QuizDataCreation.new(user: current_user)
```

Change it to

```
QuizDataCreation.new(current_user)
```

or change method signature to accept keyword args.

Comment: Learned something new about parameters, thank you! That fixed it! :)